# What does the ^ (caret) symbol do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, math, operators

I have some JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#calcular').click(function() {
    var altura2 = ((($('#ddl_altura').attr("value"))/100)^2);
    var peso = $('#ddl_peso').attr("value");
    var resultado = Math.round(parseFloat(peso / altura2)*100)/100;
    if (resultado > 0) {
      $('#resultado').html(resultado);
      $('#imc').show();
    };
  });
});
</script>
```

What does the `^` (caret) symbol mean in JavaScript?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The [`^` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) is the bitwise XOR operator. To square a value, use [`Math.pow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow):

```
var altura2 = Math.pow($('#ddl_altura').attr("value")/100, 2);
```

Comment: in a language like Javascript where types are so loose they barely exist, i'm almost surprised there are even bitwise operations :)

Comment: I know the pow function (the Loreal Web Master seems no...) but I couldn´t find the ^ operator for javascript. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Nice catch! Forwarded it to my spanish friend, who got a little shocked. Noticed how for example 200cm/70kg gives you a BMI of infinity ;-)

Comment: Haha, that´s the same test I did!! now I know the answer, I feel better. I was scared for having a BMI of infinity...

Comment: To square a value, multiply it by itself.  It's faster and more accurate on almost all platforms.

Comment: Gets much easier in ES7  : `2**5 //32`

Answer (score 54):

`^` is performing exclusive OR (XOR), for instance

`6` is `110` in binary, `3` is `011` in binary, and

`6 ^ 3`, meaning `110 XOR 011` gives 101 (5).

```
  110   since 0 ^ 0 => 0
  011         0 ^ 1 => 1
  ---         1 ^ 0 => 1
  101         1 ^ 1 => 0
```

Math.pow(x,2) calculates `x²` but for square you better use `x*x` as Math.pow uses logarithms and you get more approximations errors. ( `x² ~ exp(2.log(x))` )

Comment: Wasn't aware of the logarithm fact! Thanks! (It's thus probably also faster, isn't it?)

Comment: Likely to be faster (while math processors are pretty fast for `double` simple operations - log is likely to be slower, while using an optimization of the Taylor series).

Comment: Wonder why Math.pow doesn't just use x*x ?!

Comment: @Jowen for x² ... But what if you need to calculate x^2.123123?

Answer (score 6):

**Its called bitwise XOR. Let me explain it:**

You have :

```
Decimal Binary   
0         0
1         01
2         10
3         11
```

Now we want `3^2=` ?
then we have `11^10=?`

```
11
10
---
01
---
```

so `11^10=01`
`01` in Decimal is `1`.

So we can say that `3^2=1;`

Answer (score 5):

This is the bitwise XOR operator.

Answer (score 1):

> The bitwise XOR operator is indicated
>   by a caret ( ^ ) and, of course, works
>   directly on the binary form of
>   numbers. Bitwise XOR is different from
>   bitwise OR in that it returns 1 only
>   when exactly one bit has a value of 1.

Source: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=820