# What is the purpose of the operator "^"?

Tags: javascript, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the ^ operator do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618340/what-does-the-operator-do)

```
>>> var foo = [1,2]
>>> var bar = [3,4]
>>> foo ^ bar
0
>>> foo ^ 3
3
>>> 1^3
2
```

What is the purpose of the operator: ^?

Edit 1: Can you explain why

```
>>> foo ^ bar
0
```

?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.5E_(Bitwise_XOR)

Comment: It's the bitwise XOR operator..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the case of `1^3`, the XOR operator does some binary stuff to get 2.

```
    1 = 00000001 ^
    3 = 00000011
        ========
        00000010 = 2
```

JavaScript sees the array syntax `[x,y]` as `NaN` when you start doing math-y things with it. `NaN` is interpreted as `0` when you do bitwise operations on it, so the `foo` and `bar` math starts to make sense taking that into account:

```
foo => NaN = 00000000 ^
bar => NaN = 00000000
             ========
             00000000 = 0

foo => NaN = 00000000 ^
         3 = 00000011
             ========
             00000011 = 3
```

Which seems to hold true. `[1,2]^7 = 7`, `[1,2,3]^9 = 9`, etc.

Comment: What about XOR with foo & bar?

Comment: @hungryMind: `+[1,2]` is `NaN`, and `NaN ^ 3` is `3`, because `NaN` will be converted to `0` in the `ToInt32` operation as defined in section 11.10 of the ECMAScript specification.

Comment: That's the answer he was expecting I think. Anyone can easily find details of XOR, but operator between array and number was his concern. Thanks for clarification

Answer (score 3):

[Bitwise XOR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.5E_%28Bitwise_XOR%29)

Answer (score 1):

Its called one of Bitwise operator,it treat their operands as a sequence of 32 bits (zeros and ones), rather than as decimal, hexadecimal, or octal numbers.Bitwise XOR (a ^ b) Returns a one in each bit position for which the corresponding bits of either but not both operands are ones.

EDIT:

```
a b a XOR b 
0 0 0 
0 1 1 
1 0 1 
1 1 0
```

and also

```
 9 (base 10) = 00000000000000000000000000001001 (base 2)
 14 (base 10) = 00000000000000000000000000001110 (base 2)
                   --------------------------------
14 ^ 9 (base 10) = 00000000000000000000000000000111 (base 2) = 7 (base 10)
```

Comment: I think you should at least state *where* you copied/pasted this from.

Comment: I don't mind but your sentence doesn't read pretty. Anyway, it's surprising they put the exact same example and sentence from your book on https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators :)

Comment: @pimvdb, sorry for saying like that in my last comment but I have seen in one of my book given by my lecturer.