# What does the caret symbol (^) do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I thought that `Math.pow(2,2)` was equal to `2^2` but it is not. So what does `^` (caret) mean in JavaScript?

I was executing some tests in the console but didn't recognize the results:

```
2 ^ 2 = 0
2 ^ 3 = 1
1 ^ 2 = 3
```

Comment: [Bitwise XOR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618340/what-does-the-operator-do)

Comment: in **most** language its **bitwise XOR**

Comment: Use operator ** for power (exponentiation) see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907063/javascript-exponents

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It means [bitwise XOR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_XOR).

**EDIT**: Fixed link

Comment: New link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Bitwise_operators

Comment: @auipga This is a link to bitwise operators in general. I've fixed my link for bitwise XOR specifically.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bitwise integer XOR operation ([MDC link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)).

Answer (score 2):

The ^ operator is bitwise XOR, you have more information in MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Answer (score 2):

That operator performs the logical XOR operation. (out bit is 1 when both input bits are different).

Answer (score 1):

This is the bitwise XOR operator, which returns a one for each position where one (not both) of the corresponding bits of its operands is a one. The next example returns 4 (0100):

```
Code: 
result = a ^ b;
```