# Calculate speed from velocity vector using box2d GetLinearVelocity();

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, box2dweb, velocity.js

I need to find the speed of an object in a game. The game is made in HTML5 with jquery and jquery.box2d.
For this I can use these methods:

```
 GetLinearVelocity().x;
 GetLinearVelocity().y;
```

I'm then trying to calculate the speed from this piece of code, but get some values that doesn't make sense when I console.log it. This is my code:

```
 var heroVelX = game.currentHero.GetLinearVelocity().x;
 var heroVelY = game.currentHero.GetLinearVelocity().y;

 var speed = Math.sqrt(heroVelX^2 + heroVelY^2);
 console.log(speed);
```

Some of the values in console.log are numbers, but most of them are NaN (Not-A-Number), which confuses me? Can someone help me solve this?

The goal I want to achieve, is to see when the speed(of object .currenHero) drop below a certain value, so I can excute a new state in the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using the wrong operator ([Bitwise XOR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.5E_%28Bitwise_XOR%29)) for doing square - [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768393/what-does-the-caret-symbol-do-in-javascript).

What you need to do is:

```
var speed = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(heroVelX, 2) + Math.pow(heroVelY, 2));
```

Comment: right answer, but `Math.pow(foo, 2)` is overkill in the circumstances compared to just writing `foo * foo`.

Comment: @Alnitak whatever your style may be, this is the most straight forward way in JS.

Comment: I see your point with `foo * foo` being more simple, just trying to get a positive value.

Comment: @ydaniv no, the most straight-forward way is merely `var speed = Math.sqrt(heroVelX * heroVelX + heroVelY * heroVelY)`

Comment: You can just do `heroVelX ** 2` now anyway.

Answer (score -2):

The only time the square root function should return NaN is when the value being square rooted is negative. A way to go about testing if this is the issue would be to try squaring the values in a different line of code before square rooting them.

```
heroVelX = (heroVelX) * (heroVelX)
```

Another way to potentially shine some light on the problem would be to add log statements printing out the values of the velocities and the velocities squared before square rooting.

Comment: I do get negative values if I log the the input before I do Math.sqrt. Do jqeury have a way to convert tve values to only positives?

Comment: Taking the absolute value will return the positive number with the same magnitude.
So Math.abs(-10) = 10

Comment: Thanks George. I'll try that.

Comment: -1 for missing the utterly bleeding obvious misuse of the `^` operator.