# When i pass arguments it consoles an Error, when i pass an empty array it consoles an empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays

When i pass arguments it consoles an Error(cannot read property "map" of undefined), when i pass an empty array it consoles an empty array :)

```
Array.prototype.square = function() {
  return [].map((number) => number^2)
}

var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(numbers.square())
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Math.pow()`

```js
Array.prototype.square = function() {
  return this.map(function(item) {
    return Math.pow(item, 2);
  });
}
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(numbers.square())
```

Answer (score 1):

You are applying **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** on an empty array so it will always return empty array, instead use `this` to refer the array. Use **[`Math .pow()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow)** to get square of the array element.

```js
Array.prototype.square = function() {
  return this.map((number) => Math.pow(number, 2))
}
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(numbers.square())
```

---

**FYI :** [`^` (caret symbol) using for bitwise XOR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.5E_%28Bitwise_XOR%29) in JavaScript, refer : [What does the caret symbol (^) do in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768393/what-does-the-caret-symbol-do-in-javascript)