# I can't get eval() to work with my javascript calculation

Tags: javascript, eval, pi

I am working on a javascript code which calculates the value of Pi. So here's the problem. When `eval()` calculates the string which is generated by the code it ***returns 1***. It is supposed to ***return 1.49138888889*** (which is a rough value of `Pi^2/6`).

Here's the code. It returns the correct calculation as a string, But `eval()` doesn't calculate it properly.

```
function calculate() {
  var times = 10;
  var functionpart1 = "1/";
  var functionpart2 = "^2+";
  var x;
  for (var functionpistring = "", x = 1; times != 0; times--, x++) {
    functionpistring = functionpistring + functionpart1 + x.toString() + functionpart2;
  }
  document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = eval(functionpistring.slice(0, functionpistring.length - 1));
}
```

Comment: I suspect you are confusing [XOR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618340/javascript-what-does-the-caret-operator-do) with [pow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow).

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: I actually got it to calculate perfectly now that I used Math.pow()

Answer (score 0):

```
function calculate() {
    var times = 20, // max loops
        x,          // counter
        f = 0,      // value representation
        s = '';     // string representation
    function square(x) {
        return x * x;
    }
    function inv(x) {
        return 1 / x;
    }
    function squareS(x) {
        return x + '²';
    }
    function invS(x) {
        return '1 / ' + x;
    }
    for (x = 0; x < times; x++) {
        f += square(inv(x));
        s += (s.length ? ' + ' : '') + squareS(invS(x));
        document.write(f + ' = ' + s);
    }
}
calculate();
```