# How to get the real value in a mathematic function

Tags: javascript, java

hello everyone i have this code that makes functions in mathematics but with this function the result is wrong o.O

x=0

> "-3*X^2-16*X+2"

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
        engine.put("X", 0);

        Object operation = engine.eval("-3*X^2-16*X+2");
        //Object operation2 = engine.eval("(X+3)");

        System.out.println("Evaluado operacion 1: " + operation);
        //System.out.println("Evaluado operacion 2: " + operation2);

    }
```

the result is 2 but i get 4

> Evaluado operacion 1: 4

i have other code that i made

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package gustavo_santa;

import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author osmarvirux
 */
public class SerieB {
    //xi and x4
    int xi;
    int x4;
    //f(x) function variables
    String positive_negative;
    int num_one;
    int elevation_one;
    String add_subtract_one;
    int num_two;
    int elevation_two;
    String add_subtract_two;
    int num_three;
    //results
    String xi_result;
    String x4_result;

    public SerieB(int xi, int x4, String positive_negative, int num_one, int elevation_one, String add_subtract_one, int num_two, int elevation_two, String add_subtract_two, int num_three) {
        this.xi = xi;
        this.x4 = x4;
        this.positive_negative = positive_negative;
        this.num_one = num_one;
        this.elevation_one = elevation_one;
        this.add_subtract_one = add_subtract_one;
        this.num_two = num_two;
        this.elevation_two = elevation_two;
        this.add_subtract_two = add_subtract_two;
        this.num_three = num_three;
    }

    public void Procedure_xi(){
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
        if (positive_negative == "-"){

           try {
            xi_result=(num_one*(Math.pow(xi, elevation_one)))+add_subtract_one+(num_two*(Math.pow(xi, elevation_two)))
                    +add_subtract_two+num_three;
            Object result = engine.eval(xi_result);
            System.out.println(xi_result+" = "+result);
            } catch(ScriptException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }           
        }else{
             try {
            xi_result=((-num_one*(Math.pow(xi, elevation_one)))+add_subtract_one+(num_two*(Math.pow(xi, elevation_two)))
            +add_subtract_two+num_three);
            Object result = engine.eval(xi_result);
            System.out.println(xi_result+" = "+result);
            } catch(ScriptException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }       

        }
    }
    public void Procedure_x4(){
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
        if (positive_negative == "-"){

           try {
            x4_result=(num_one*(Math.pow(x4, elevation_one)))+add_subtract_one+(num_two*(Math.pow(x4, elevation_two)))
                    +add_subtract_two+num_three;
            Object result = engine.eval(x4_result);
            System.out.println(x4_result+" = "+result);
            } catch(ScriptException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }           
        }else{
             try {
            x4_result=((-num_one*(Math.pow(x4, elevation_one)))+add_subtract_one+(num_two*(Math.pow(x4, elevation_two)))
            +add_subtract_two+num_three);
            Object result = engine.eval(x4_result);
            System.out.println(x4_result+" = "+result);
            } catch(ScriptException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }       

        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //-3x^2-16x+2
        SerieB obj = new SerieB(0, 1, "+", -3, 2, "-", 16, 1, "+", 2);
        obj.Procedure_xi();
        obj.Procedure_x4();
    }


}
```

the result with this code is 2 but i wanna use

> ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();

because is a library and i think is more precise and i dont wanna use my code because there are many lines and i dont know if is 100% efficient. someone can help me? or give me a recomendation to resolve this mathematic functions? thanks a lot

Comment: The issue is that `^` means bitwise exclusive or, rather than exponentiation.  But I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Consider adding a JavaScript tag to this question since you're using a JavaScript script engine.

Comment: i added JavaScript tag bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you're getting is correct.

The confusion arises from the fact that what you're assuming to be the power operator (`^`) is actually the [bitwise XOR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.5E_%28Bitwise_XOR%29) operator in JavaScript (you're using a JavaScript script engine).

So, evaluating `0 ^ 2` yields `2`, while evaluating `Math.pow(0, 2)` yields `0`, hence the difference.

To get the result you expect, the expression would have to read:

```
-3*Math.pow(X,2)-16*X+2
```

You could pre-process the expression to replace the exponential operations with invocations of `Math.pow()`:

```js
let X = 0;
let expression = "-3*X^2-16*X+2"
let processed = expression.replace(/(\w+)\^(\w+)/g, 'Math.pow($1,$2)');

console.log(processed); // prints "-3*Math.pow(X,2)-16*X+2"
console.log(eval(processed)); // prints "2"
```

Using the script engine, that could look like:

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
engine.put("X", 0);
engine.put("expression", "-3*X^2-16*X+2");
engine.put("processed", engine.eval("expression.replace(/(\\w+)\\^(\\w+)/g, 'Math.pow($1,$2)')"));

System.out.println(engine.eval("eval(processed)")); // 2.0
```

Or, if you prefer to do the regular expression replacement in Java:

```
String expression = "-3*X^2-16*X+2";
String processed = expression.replaceAll("(\\w+)\\^(\\w+)", "Math.pow($1,$2)");

ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
engine.put("X", 0);

System.out.println(engine.eval(processed)); // 2.0
```

Comment: `Math.pow(0,2)` means 0 to the power of 2 which should yield 0 not 1

Comment: but i wanna get the information of a String how would be the text? because the user cant write "-3*Math.pow(X,2)-16*X+2" in a string brother :(

Comment: @MatthewCiaramitaro Thx. Typo.

Comment: @AlienJava See the last part of my answer

Comment: @AlienJava Don't add answers or partial answers to your question. I'll update my answer with a Java snippet

Comment: @AlienJava that text should be applied to the String inside the eval not to the Object you created. the string must be changed before you evaluate it

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen AWESOME SR!!

Comment: @AlienJava Now please remove the partial answer from your question. Your question stands  as is, so does my answer.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen im sorry i dont undertand at all brother im a little noob in stackoverflow and im not a native english speaker. can you be more specific?

Comment: The point is: things get really confusing if you start adding answers or partial answers to your question. Roll it back to its original state.

Comment: Delete everything including and after "i tried with this but i get syntax error :( im using netbeans (java 8.1)"

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen brother i already updated the question, Matthew Ciaramitaro helped me with his information. did i do the correct? or do you wanna i delete more information?

Comment: @AlienJava Looks great, thanks. I even gave you my upvote back :)

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen can you help me with one exercise? i can pay you some dollars with paypal teacher! please i believe 1 day you finish it.. in java. i hope your answer

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening is your program is evaluating

```
(-3*0)^2 - 16*0 + 2 = 0^2 +2 = 2+2 =4
```

because the operator `^` in computer science mean bitwise exclusive or,
which basically means if the bits are both 1 or 0 then change them to 0, else 1. And 2 is represented by `10` while 0 is `0` so `2^0 = 2`

Try replacing `^2` with `*X`
alternatively you can use `Math.pow(X,n)` , if you need exponentiation to some power `n`, but for squaring it's better to just write it out as `X*X`

The Below is Outdated Due to Edits to Question, but is still functional:

In the second part of your question you wrote

```
Object operation = engine.eval("-3*(X^2)-16*X +2");
String processed = operation.replace(/(\w+)\^(\w+)/g, 'Math.pow($1,$2)');
```

based on an answer by another user. You should have written

```
String expr = "-3*(X^2)-16*X +2";
String processed = expr.replaceAll("(\\w+)(\\^)(\\w+)", 'Math.pow($1,$2'));
Object operation = engine.eval(processed);
```

Comment: That won't compile.

Comment: Is that a regex thing?

Comment: ya Ik... give me a sec

Comment: I just finished and noticed you'd already added this version to your answer.... that's what I get for being slow

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect syntax for power. Replace `-3*X^2-16*X+2` with `-3*Math.pow(X,2)-16*X+2`. See [Javascript, What does the ^ (caret) operator do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618340/javascript-what-does-the-caret-operator-do)