# how do i make shorten this code that makes circles into an array?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Im using the p5.js library and cannot format a for loop properly to display these circles:

```
function draw() {
  ellipse(width/12,height/2,width/6,width/6);    
  ellipse(width/12,height/4,width/12,width/12);
  ellipse(width/12,height/8,width/24,width/24);
  ellipse(width/12,height/16,width/48,width/48);
}
```

i have tried the following but no ellipses are made. where am i going wrong?

below i have attached the full code.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
  ellipse(width/12, height/(2 * (2^i)), width/(6 * (2^i)), width/(6 * (2^i));  
}
```

```js
function setup() {
  canvas = createCanvas(windowWidth,windowHeight);
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  fill( 149, 185, 241,160);
  rect(width*(1/6),0,width*(2/3),height);
  
  
  fill(181,99,87,160);
  noStroke();
  
  for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
  ellipse(width/12, height/(2* pow(2,i)), width/(6 * pow(2,i)), width/(6 * pow(2,i));  
}

  
}


window.onresize = function() {
  canvas.size(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}
```

Comment: Are you able to make ellipses without the forloop

Comment: use `Math.pow` over `^`.

Comment: they display without the forloop, but when i add it nothing appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't doing what you think it is:

```
2^i
```

That's a bitwise xor operator. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618340/javascript-what-does-the-caret-operator-do) for more info, and Google is your friend.

You're probably looking for the P5.js `pow()` function. More info can be found in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/pow).

You should get into the habit of [debugging](http://HappyCoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) your code. When you have questions like this, try printing out the value of each parameter. You would have been able to isolate your problem, which makes Googling easier.

For example, do this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
  console.log('i: ' + i);
  console.log('width: ' + width);
  console.log('width/12: ' + width/12);
  console.log('pow(2,i): ' + pow(2,i));
  console.log('height/(2* pow(2,i)): ' + height/(2* pow(2,i)));
  console.log('width/(6 * pow(2,i)): ' + width/(6 * pow(2,i)));
  ellipse(width/12, height/(2* pow(2,i)), width/(6 * pow(2,i)), width/(6 * pow(2,i)));  
}
```

This will tell you exactly which parameter is different from what you expected, and you can further isolate your problem from there.

Of course, that also requires you to check the [developer console](http://HappyCoding.io/tutorials/javascript/developer-tools), which you should also really get into the habit of doing. That's where any errors you're encountering will be shown. The code currently in your question is missing a `)` closing parenthesis on the `ellipse()` line.

If you have a follow-up question, please try to post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can copy and paste to run ourselves instead of a disconnected snippet of code.

Comment: sorry will try and use a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Comment: @MatthewMcLeod Like I said, you need to debug your code and post a [mcve] if you have follow-up questions. Comments are not for code. Please edit your question or post a new question in its own post.

Comment: @MatthewMcLeod Please see my edited answer with more info on how to debug your problem.

Comment: @MatthewMcLeod Also note that you're missing a `)` closing parentheses in your `ellipse()` line. Please see my edited answer again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [left shift `<<`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Left_shift) operator, because you are using factor 2, like

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    ellipse(width / 12, height / (2 << i), width / (6 * (2 << i)), width / (6 * (2 << i));
}
```

```js
console.log(2 << 0, 2 << 1, 2 << 2, 2 << 3);
```