# clarity on the meaning of this javascript math object syntax

Tags: javascript

I was going through a small program  and i came across this syntax in javascript.

```
hash = Math.abs((hash << 2) ^ (hash + y))
```

please what does it mean?

hash was initially 0; i.e `hash = 0`;

Comment: no more context?

Comment: `<<` is a bitwise operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Left_shift. `hash << 2` is equivalent to the math operation of `hash * Math.pow(2, 2)`

Comment: [`<<` - bitwise shift left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535328/what-do-these-javascript-bitwise-operators-do) [`^` - bitwise XOR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618340/javascript-what-does-the-caret-operator-do). And `+` is addition, `Math.abs` is absolute value.

Comment: thanks. It really helped