# what does ^= mean in js

Tags: javascript, operators

I was on leetcode and I saw this symbol in the discuss section

```js
var singleNumber = function(nums) {
    let result = 0;
    
    nums.forEach((num) => result ^= num)
    
    return result;
};
```

please please make me understand the solution [leetcode solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/single-number/discuss/1806217/JavaScript-Simple-Solution-oror-faster-than-95.60)

Comment: Relevant: [What does the ^ (caret) symbol do in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3618340)

Comment: see: [Bitwise XOR assignment (^=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_XOR_assignment)

Comment: @gre_gor it's not explicitly answered in that question, but the components are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Bitwise XOR assignment (^=)

The bitwise XOR assignment operator (^=) uses the binary representation of both operands, does a bitwise XOR operation on them and assigns the result to the variable.

[Source: MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_XOR_assignment)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).